# Checkbox and radio inputs in WordPress back end do not preserve their checked status

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added new fields with input type text in the back-end of WordPress, but what about other types? I have tried with no results. Every time I update the property I have to mark with a check again to keep the fields selected. The checkmark is not preserved.

Here is what I’m doing.

```
<?php $mb->the_field( 'petsallowed' ); ?>
        <input type="radio" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value('Yes'); ?>" <?php checked( $mb->get_the_value() ); ?>/>Yes
        <input type="radio" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value('No'); ?>" <?php checked( $mb->get_the_value() ); ?>/>No
        <input type="radio" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value('Ask'); ?>" <?php checked( $mb->get_the_value() ); ?>/>Ask
```

What I need/want to do is avoid the input checked

Now I have this:

```
<?php $mb->the_field( 'pet_yes' ); ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="1" <?php checked( $mb->get_the_value() ); ?>/>
    <label>Yes</label>

    <?php $mb->the_field( 'pet_no' ); ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="1" <?php checked( $mb->get_the_value() ); ?>/>
    <label>No</label>

    <?php $mb->the_field( 'pet_ask' ); ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="1" <?php checked( $mb->get_the_value() ); ?>/>
    <label>Ask</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="radio" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value('Yes'); ?>" <?php checked( $mb->get_the_value(),$mb->the_value('Yes') ); ?>/>Yes
        <input type="radio" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value('No'); ?>" <?php checked( $mb->get_the_value(),mb->the_value('No') ); ?>/>No
        <input type="radio" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value('Ask'); ?>" <?php checked( $mb->get_the_value(),$mb->the_value('Ask') ); ?>/>Ask
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you, almost works. For some reason the last radio is always checked. I also tried including the field name but no results. Now I have this:

Comment: <?php $mb->the_field( 'pet_yes' ); ?>
 <input type="checkbox" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="1" <?php checked( $mb->get_the_value() ); ?>/>
        <label>Yes</label>

Comment: <?php $mb->the_field( 'pet_no' ); ?>
 <input type="checkbox" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="1" <?php checked( $mb->get_the_value() ); ?>/>
        <label>No</label>
        
        <?php $mb->the_field( 'pet_ask' ); ?>
 <input type="checkbox" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="1" <?php checked( $mb->get_the_value() ); ?>/>
        <label>Ask</label>